# How to use MutationObserver in Google Tag Manager to detect a new element in DOM?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to detect an element being added to my div in GTM. I'm using Angular 8 and I'm not sure if Angular triggers a DOMNodeInserted event. Here's my code in GTM:

```
function () {
  return $('.taglist-list.what').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function(element){
    console.log('dom changed');

    if($(this).hasClass('gtm--user-generated-what')){
      console.log(element.target);
    }

  });
}
```

The `dom-changed` is never triggered.

Comment: Even if it did trigger the event, you would be relying on an implementation detail that would be subject to change without notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done similar work in Google Tag Manager using mutation observers. They're supported in pretty much every modern browser.

Here is how it could be used for your specific problem with vanilla mutation observers (and your jquery added into the function):

```
var mutationTarget = document.querySelector('.taglist-list.what');
var observedAtts = {attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false};

var mutationFunction = function(mutationList, observer) {
  mutationList.forEach(function (mutation) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
       mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(elem) {
          if($(elem).hasClass('gtm--user-generated-what')){
             console.log(element.target);
          }
       });
    }
  });
};

var obs = new MutationObserver(mutationFunction);
obs.observe(mutationTarget, observedAtts);
```

Here is a generic example:
https://codepen.io/abissonnette/pen/yLeLYjo

There is maybe more of a discussion around "should GTM be used for this kind of hacky stuff". Especially as @Aluan points out above - the implementation would be subject to change without notice. There are many things we shouldn't do but if there is a business need for it then you'll have to weight the risk vs rewards.